# File transfer from Windows Server 2012 to Synology Disk Station creates an empty file

Tags: ftp, nas, windows-server-2012-r2, mikrotik-routeros

We have a software that makes a report on our computers. It generates a .csv file.
I have to transfer it from the server to Synology disk station.

I have created a FTP script.

```
Open X.X.X.X
username
password
cd /Synology-directory-of-file
delete file.csv
lcd C:\directory-where-file-is-created
put file.csv
quit
```

This was working fine until last Friday. Now I get

```
500 illegal PORT range rejected.
```

I still can copy the file manually with no problems. However when I do this with the script, it creates an empty file.

What happened on Friday - we changed one of our routers to a Mikrotik. I'm looking in to this, if this could block the script.

Answer (score 0):

Had to enable Mikrotik Firewall FTP Service Port